# Flutter: Is the build number/version code optional or mandatory?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-play, google-play-console

I added my app bundle to the Google Console for internal testing and the version was

```
version: 1.0.0+1
```

Now I want to add some fixes and so upgraded the app version and removed the build number

```
version: 1.0.1
```

But Google Play gives the below error

**Version code 1 has already been used. Try another version code.**

1. But if the the build number is optional as mentioned by the
   documentation then why is it giving an error?
2. Will I always have to add build number and increment no matter the
   major and minor versions?

https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#updating-the-apps-version-number**

> The version number is three numbers separated by dots, such as 1.0.0
> in the example above, followed by an optional build number such as 1
> in the example above, separated by a +.

Answer (score 0):

in a Flutter project, what define the name of the version is the `1.0.1`, but what define the count of the update is `+1`, so by setting version like this:

```
version: 1.0.1+1
```

you say 'the name of this version is 1.0.1, it's my first ( +1 ) update', so the next time when you set it like this:

```
 version: 1.0.2+1
```

you say 'the name of this version is 1.0.2, it's my first ( +1 ) update'.

and here the `Google play console` throws that error to you to change it, it uses that `+1` to know how it should list your app version in the console, so you need a different one every time you update your app, you need to do like this as an example:

```
 version: 1.0.2+2
```

after the build, when you upload it, it will work fine.

But Note: if you uploaded for the next time with a different version, and they rejected it again for example the :

> You must complete the advertising ID declaration before you can release an app that targets Android 13 (API 33). We'll use this declaration to provide safeguards in Play Console to accommodate changes to advertising ID in Android 13.

even if it's rejected, it remember new upload with that version code, so after fixing the issue, you need to either change again the version code and re-upload again, or you can in your console to delete the rejected previous uploaded app to it's version code.